# How to recover my Jira project after I lose log-in

Tags: firefox, jira

My Ubuntu failed so I had to reinstall and I lost all my Firefox bookmarks, passwords in the process. It's my fault and I should stop depending on major software companies to watch my back I guess.

I exported and printed my Jira issues before the crash so I have links to specific issues, to the project and for Reporter, which is me.

[image: myissues]

But when I click any of those links, it takes me to the Jira site and then tells me this account does not have access to the project.
What's frustrating is that at one point one of the emails I thought I used worked for login, I could see my project name but there is no link for it.

I have emailed them asking them to send me just a csv or something with all my issues so I can move on to another issue tracking software but does anyone know how I can get this now?